# Kuberentes deployment Pod not getting created

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

My spring is deployed on kubernetes using docker desktop it was working ok its scale up and down suddenly the deployement get stuck in 0/1 with 0 availebal pod

kubectl describe replicaset consumer-deployment-8487d9fdf6^C shows

```
 Service Account:  spring-boot
  Containers:
   consumer-container:
    Image:      myrepo/repo:tagname
    Port:       8087/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Requests:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  512Mi
    Environment:
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST:          172.17.0.2
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME:      guest
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD:      guest
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_VIRTUAL_HOST:  /
    Mounts:                          <none>
  Volumes:                           <none>
Conditions:
  Type             Status  Reason
  ----             ------  ------
  ReplicaFailure   True    FailedCreate
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                 From                   Message
  ----     ------        ----                ----                   -------
  Warning  FailedCreate  94s (x18 over 12m)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: pods "consumer-deployment-8487d9fdf6-" is forbidden: error looking up service account default/spring-boot: serviceaccount "spring-boot" not found
```

Kubectl describe nodes shows this

```
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    44m (x8 over 44m)    kubelet          Node docker-desktop status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  44m (x8 over 44m)    kubelet          Node docker-desktop status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   RegisteredNode           43m                  node-controller  Node docker-desktop event: Registered Node docker-desktop in Controller
  Normal   Starting                 34m                  kubelet          Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  34m                  kubelet          Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  34m (x8 over 34m)    kubelet          Node docker-desktop status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    34m (x8 over 34m)    kubelet          Node docker-desktop status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     34m (x7 over 34m)    kubelet          Node docker-desktop status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   RegisteredNode           33m                  node-controller  Node docker-desktop event: Registered Node docker-desktop in Controller
```

I tryed prune command and it remove about 6GB but the probleme still persist

```
docker system prune
```

k describe deployment gives this

```
kubectl describe deployment/consumer-deployment
Name:                   consumer-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Mon, 12 Jun 2023 11:08:13 +0100
Labels:                 app=consumer-app
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=consumer-app
Replicas:               1 desired | 0 updated | 0 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=consumer-app
  Service Account:  spring-boot
  Containers:
   consumer-container:
    Image:      repo/myrepo:tagname
    Port:       8087/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Requests:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  512Mi
    Environment:
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST:          172.17.0.2
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME:      guest
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD:      guest
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_VIRTUAL_HOST:  /
    Mounts:                          <none>
  Volumes:                           <none>
Conditions:
  Type             Status  Reason
  ----             ------  ------
  Progressing      True    NewReplicaSetCreated
  Available        False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  ReplicaFailure   True    FailedCreate
OldReplicaSets:    <none>
NewReplicaSet:     consumer-deployment-8487d9fdf6 (0/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age    From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----   ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  9m38s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set consumer-deployment-8487d9fdf6 to 1
```

Is there anythin else i need to look into it ??

Comment: You seem to have included a lot of diagnostic information, but not any of the actual source code necessary to demonstrate the issue.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The one other diagnostic thing I might immediately look at is the `kubectl describe replicaset consumer-deployment-8487d9fdf6` output, since that's what's actually creating the Pods.

Comment: you are correct the command you provided shows thing unlike the other I pasted the output of it can you please take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the appended output you provided

```
  Warning  FailedCreate  94s (x18 over 12m)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: pods "consumer-deployment-8487d9fdf6-" is forbidden: error looking up service account default/spring-boot: serviceaccount "spring-boot" not found
```

You are trying to create the deployment using a service account which, presumably, doesn't exist.

Comment: I added a service and it worked thanks
```
 kubectl create serviceaccount spring-boot

```